# Password protected directory [c-panel] - receiving no login prompt when the url is clicked in FB Messenger

Tags: htaccess, cpanel, http-authentication

The public_html folder is password-protected via the .htaccess file. I'm using an Apache web server and hosting on Godaddy.

It works fine if I use any browser on mobile and desktop/laptop devices.

But when the website URL is sent as a link and clicked in Facebook Messenger with any mobile device, we get a 401 Unauthorized error. It seems like that the Messenger webview skips the login pop-up window and goes straight to 401 error.  Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like that the Messenger webview skips the login pop-up window and goes straight to 401 error.

The "401 error" is always there. The "login pop-up window" is generated by the supporting user-agent (eg. the browser) in answer to the 401 Unauthorised response and appropriate `WWW-Authenticate` header.

It would seem the "Facebook Messenger webview" component does not support HTTP Authentication so does not generate a login prompt.

---

However, both iOS and Android "FB Messenger webview" have the secondary option to open in Safari/Chrome browser which then naturally triggers the login prompt.